# How do I get positional and entity data in an execute command in minecraft? [1.17.1]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to write a command that gives a player a score of 1 if they are standing on a gold block:

```
/execute at @a if block ~ ~-2 ~ minecraft:gold_block run scoreboard players set @s gold 1
```

The problem is that I need the position of the player but also their entity data. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Exactly what data are you looking to check? I've posted a generic answer that works for any entity data below but you should please clarify. ([edit] your post)

Comment: Also, note that ~-2 will not be the block directly bellow the player.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `nbt=` argument in the target selector:

```
execute at @a[nbt={…}] if block ~ ~-2 ~ minecraft:gold_block run scoreboard players set @s gold 1
```

NBT checks are performance heavy and should be avoided if possible in favour of other methods. Please be aware.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly the issue you have is that you execute `at` the players, which is enough to be able to check things about their position, but if you then want to be able to know which player it was, you should also execute `as` them.

`at` changes the command contexts position
`as` changes the command contexts executor

So, your fixed command would be

```
execute as @a at @s if block ~ ~-2 ~ minecraft:gold_block run scoreboard players set @s gold 1
```